# copy a file with scp, which is not stored on a filesystem

Tags: linux, shell, scp

I need to copy a .war file, which i currently just can reach over the UI with "http://server:host/directory/my_file.war". So its not stored on a fileserver. Im logged on a server A and the file needs to be saved on server B.

Is it in general possible to download files from a server A, that are not stored on a fileserver with the scp command to a server B?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, scp does not support `http:`. First copy the file to your computer using `curl` or `wget` (or save it with your browser), and then use scp to copy from a local filesystem.

If you have shell access on server B, just ssh to server B, and run `wget` there to pull the file down directly. This is better in that it only uses bandwidth on serverB and the webserver (in case that matters to you) -- see below for an alternative solution that uses much more bandwidth.

Or, if for some reason you can't download the file directly to server B, do something like:

```
serverA$ wget --output-document=- http://server:host/directory/my_file.war | \
    ssh user@serverB "cat > /path/to/my_file.war"
```

This tells `wget` to fetch the URL to stdout, and then `ssh` will send that data to serverB and redirect it to a file. Unfortunately, `scp` can't read a from stdin, so you will need shell access on serverB in order for this to work. Note that if you do this, you'll use 2x bandwidth on serverA (to pull the file from the webserver, and then push it to server B), and you'll use 1x bandwidth on the webserver and serverB.

Comment: with wget its possible to save the file directly to the target server. but is there a security risk compared to scp?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "target server" -- the machine where you're running the `wget` command? If you are downloading via http (and not **https**), then the security risks are inherent in the http protocol and there's nothing `scp` could do to change that.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i edited the question a bit. With "target server" i mean the "server B", where i want to copy the file. 
First i have to connect with the server B with ssh. then i want to download the file. And according to your answer i have to use "wget" to download it first on the server A (where im logged in), and then copy it with scp to server B. So there is no one-step-solution. right?

Comment: Do you have a shell on server B? Or just scp and no shell access on server B?

Comment: I think i do have shell access.. why? Sorry, im really new in this.